# Querying nested objects using linq query with join

Tags: c#, json.net, linq-to-objects

I have the following json structure that I am getting from an api:

```
    {
    "event_instance": [
        {
            "id": 55551244,
            "event_id": 11112,
            "name": "Brown Belt Karate Class",
            "staff_members": [
                {
                    "id": 12345,
                    "name": "John Smith"
                }

            ],

            "people": [
                {
                    "id": 111,
                    "name": "Jane Doe"
                },
                {
                    "id": 222,
                    "name": "Josh Smith"

                },
                {
                    "id": 333,
                    "name": "Ben Johnson"
                }

            ],
            "visits": [
                {
                    "id": 1234578,
                    "person_id": 111,
                    "state": "completed",
                    "status": "complete"
                },
                {
                    "id": 1239865,
                    "person_id": 222,
                    "state": "completed",
                    "status": "complete"
                },
                {
                    "id": 1239865,
                    "person_id": 333,
                    "state": "canceled",
                    "status": "cancel"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am deserializing this into the following .net objects using JSON.NET:

```
    [JsonObjectAttribute("event_instance")]
    public class EventInstance
    {
        [JsonPropertyAttribute("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyAttribute("event_id")]
        public int EventId { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyAttribute("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyAttribute("staff_members")]
        public List<StaffMember> StaffMembers { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyAttribute("visits")]
        public List<Visit> Visits { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyAttribute("people")]
        public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
    } 

    [JsonObjectAttribute("staff_members")]
    public class StaffMember
    {
        [JsonPropertyAttribute("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyAttribute("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [JsonObjectAttribute("people")]
    public class People
    {
        [JsonPropertyAttribute("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyAttribute("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [JsonObjectAttribute("visits")]
    public class Visits
    {
        [JsonPropertyAttribute("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyAttribute("person_id")]
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyAttribute("state")]
        public string State { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyAttribute("status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
```

I am using the following code to de-serialize:

```
var event = (EventInstance)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(EventInstance));
```

The above works fine and gives me an accurate object representation of the above json structure. Now I am trying to query this event object to filter/project to a new structure that I can then serialize back to json and send down to the browser. I need to return a list of students for the event that are in a state of "completed" and a status of "complete". As you can see, the people array ties to the visits array (with id and person_id). I would like to produce the following simple output:

1. 11112, Brown Belt Karate Class, John Smith, 111, Jane Doe
2. 11112, Brown Belt Karate Class, John Smith, 222, Josh Smith

I have tried something like this:

```
var studentList =   from theClass in event
                    from staff in theClass.StaffMembers
                    from student in theClass.People
                    from visits in theClass.Visits
                    where visits.Status == "complete" 
                    && visits.State == "completed"
                           select new
                           {
                               event_id = theClass.EventId
                               class_name = theClass.Name,
                               instructor_name = staff.Name,
                               student_id = student.Id,
                               student_name = student.Name
                           };



string _data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(studentList);
```

Naturally this produces duplicate student names. I am new to linq. Basically I need to join/tie the people and visits array so I just get back a single student for that id, along with the root data for this event. Any advice on a better way to do this is much appreciated too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to join the students and visits into a collection that contains data of both:

```
from ei in eventInstances
from sm in ei.StaffMembers
from x in
(from vi in ei.Visits
 join st in ei.Students on vi.PersonId equals st.Id
 select new { vi, st }) // Here you get students and visits side-by-side
select new
{
    ei.EventId,
    Event = ei.Name,
    StaffMemeber = sm.Name,
    PersonId = x.st.Id,
    Student = x.st.Name
}
```

Comment: Ah, makes sense now. Linq will take some time to get used to. Thanks!!